# Embed Flourish Visualization in Blogdown

Tags: javascript, r, blogdown

Flourish is a [company](https://flourish.studio/) that enables you to make dynamic visualizations.

I have a blog using R Studio, blogdown, github and Netlify.

After creating a chart, Flourish provides a URL and some embed code.

```
https://public.flourish.studio/visualisation/56290/

<div class="flourish-embed" data-src="visualisation/56290"></div><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script>
```

I see how I can roughly place the treemap on my blog using an [iframe](https://lawsblog.netlify.com/).
But that is not ideal.

Is it possible to embed the code Flourish provides in blogdown? If so, how?

I was hoping it could look as clean as a leaflet-R map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just a matter of cut-and-paste? That is, paste the code in your blog post:

```
<div class="flourish-embed" data-src="visualisation/56290"></div><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script>
```

FWIW, Flourish does not recommend using iframes:

[image]

Comment: Right as always Yihui. My brain was thinking I couldn't paste the embed code directly into the post.